# Sitecore MVC does not give error for .aspx pages

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

We are using Sitecore 8.1 with MVC format. 
We just discovered that if we have a link like:
mywebsite.com/about or mywebsite.com/contact

If you write mywebsite.com/about.aspx it works as the page was there. Is this a desired functionality?
If we don't want to have only the version without .aspx how can we do that? Is this possible?

**EDIT:** this is how the url's are being generated:

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
<providers>
  <clear />
  <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="always" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
</providers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Sitecore default behavior, but what you can do, is redirect any `.aspx` page to the correct URL, keep `addAspxExtension="false"` in sitecore Link Manager configuration, and add the following code to your main layout :

```
 string itemUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item);
 if (itemUrl != Request.Path)
    {
        Response.Redirect(itemUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is default Sitecore behaviour.

It returns the page even if you add `.aspx` or `.ashx` extension.

You cannot disable this functionality without custom coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is sitecore's default behaviour.

You can remove the extension while generating the url's by passing 
urlOptions.AddAspxExtension as false.

if we want that across your website change in sitecore.config file

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

If you don't want .aspx or .ashx url's to be existed. you can override HttpRequestProcessor pipeline and do a permanent redirect on those url's which have those extensions.

Comment: we have this as configuration and it has no effect

Comment: @Radu can you post how you are generating the urls?

Comment: So, you have setup not to get .asps extension and still u are getting while genereting url's like LinkManager.GetItemUrl(path). Is that right?